# Get details about FindFirstFile Handle

Tags: winapi

I have a search handle returned by FindFirstFile.
At a later point in my program I'd like to log some details about the search (ideally the search pattern or the directory being searched) but I only have the handle available to get at those details.

For good reasons (trust me) I don't want to store those information when the search is started so my only option is to somehow query the handle.
Does the Windows API provide any function to do that? Something like GetFilenameFromSearchHandle()

I assume FindFirstFile is implemented using NtQueryDirectoryFile which works on a regular file handle, so is there a way to get from search handle to underlying file handle?

Comment: Yes, `FindFirstFile()` uses `NtOpenFile()` and `NtQueryDirectoryFile()` internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows provides no such functionality. There is no way to start with just a search handle, and query for the original parameters passed to `FindFirstFile`. You will need to make a note of those parameters when you call `FindFirstFile`.

Comment: I guess that's how it is then. :( thanks for the answer